# How to use Short datatype with @Cacheable?

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-cache

I'm trying to cache `Short` value with `@Cacheable`.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableCaching
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() { 
        return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager(); 
    }
}

@Service
public class MyCacheService {
    @Cacheable("testcache")
    public Short getId(String name) {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheResolver.resolveCaches(AbstractCacheResolver.java:78) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.getCaches(CacheAspectSupport.java:216) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport$CacheOperationContext.<init>(CacheAspectSupport.java:565) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.getOperationContext(CacheAspectSupport.java:229) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport$CacheOperationContexts.<init>(CacheAspectSupport.java:508) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:302) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
```

This is thrown because `cacheManager` is `null` in `AbstractCacheResolver`. But why?

Comment: Do you have the @Configuration annotation?

Comment: yes or course I have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, at first glance, your configuration looks (mostly) correct.  However, it really does not tell us the whole story either, i.e. in what runtime context your application is running.

You seem to be using *Spring Boot* (?) given your use of `@EnableAutoConfiguration`.  You say you have the `@Configuration` annotation yet have not provided any evidence of that.  Perhaps, contrary to popular belief, [`@AutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.4.0.RC1/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/EnableAutoConfiguration.java#L70-L76) does not declare `@Configuration` for you; [`@SpringBootApplication`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.4.0.RC1/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.java#L50) annotation does (specifically, [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.4.0.RC1/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/SpringBootConfiguration.java#L43)).

Anyway, I put together a simple *Spring Boot* application demonstrating your sample code.  It works as expected.

```
package org.examples.spring.boot.caching;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheManager;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class ConcurrentMapCachingExample implements CommandLineRunner {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ConcurrentMapCachingExample.class, args);
  }

  @Autowired
  private ExampleCacheableService exampleService;

  @Override
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    assertThat(exampleService.isCacheMiss()).isFalse();
    assertThat(exampleService.computeValue("one").intValue()).isEqualTo(1);
    assertThat(exampleService.isCacheMiss()).isTrue();
    assertThat(exampleService.computeValue("one").intValue()).isEqualTo(1);
    assertThat(exampleService.isCacheMiss()).isFalse();
  }  
}

@Service
class ExampleCacheableService {

  boolean cacheMiss;

  boolean isCacheMiss() {
    boolean cacheMiss = this.cacheMiss;
    this.cacheMiss = false;
    return cacheMiss;
  }

  @Cacheable("Example")
  public Short computeValue(String cacheKey) {
    System.out.printf("Computing value for [%s]%n", cacheKey);
    cacheMiss = true;
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Also note, given the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation [declares](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.4.0.RC1/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.java#L51) the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation for you, and that *Spring Boot's* auto configuration support automatically detects caching providers on the classpath, then just by using the `@Cacheable` annotation on your `@Service` application component along with the `@EnableCaching` annotation in your configuration, this is enough for *Spring Boot* to (auto) configure a `CacheManager` for you.

Therefore, the following `@Bean` definition is not necessary...

```
@Bean
ConcurrentMapCacheManager cacheManager() {
  return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager();
}
```

See the [Spring Boot's Reference Guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-caching) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed insight. I yet don't know why in my case it did not work. But your explaination proves that in general there should be no problem with the code.